# Eclipse WTP plugin no Apache Tomcat adapter

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, plugins, eclipse-wtp

I am using Galileo Eclipse, I downloaded WTP plugin, but no Apache Tomcat plugin when I try to add Tomcat server...

any quick idea?

Comment: The WTP plugin may have been incorrectly or partially installed.. Perhaps you should use *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*, which should have wtp by default.

Comment: As mentioned below it's not the WTP plugin, it's another plugin "JST Server Adapters" (and extensions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In WTP you can download plugins for many different web container or Java EE application servers.

To do so go to `Window` => `Preferences` => `Server` => `Runtime Environments` => `Add...`  Select the server(s) you want to work with.

However, as Raghuram as pointed out, you'd probably be better off starting from the 'Eclipse for Java EE developers` altogether.  This is because WTP is built on top of many 'infrastructure' plugins such as EMF and the dependencies are sometimes wobbly because all these plugins evolve in a parallel manner... and more often than not, API change ;-)

Comment: IMHO The answer below is a much better answer that this one.

Comment: @rustyx, the fact that the "answer below" is rated higher is just testimony to the fact that there is a significant fraction of eclipse (new) users for which it is not immediate that to run the tomcat plugin what you should naturally install is the J2EE bundle.  They start with the eclipse standard bundle and then install WTP rather than taking the easy "all included" J2EE option. A quick google search lands them here... before they stumble on the next snag and google again... Yet servlets, JSP, JSTL, JSF etc are all parts of J2EE.

Comment: @AlainPannetier, I upvoted Nitind's answer and not yours because I have found from experience that the J2EE Bundle comes with a load of components I don't want. Those components not only slow down Eclipse but also add views and menu items that make the UI harder to use. So it's perfectly valid to install standard Eclipse and then add what you need.

Comment: @a.b.d, this is where our experience differ then. Views come only with their perspectives which you can customize at will as you can customize menus and shortcuts. Plugins are loaded lazily (same for IDEA actually).  Says somebody who runs eclipse with pydev, epic (perl), c/c++, egit, subclipse and a dozen more plugins and has been using eclipse since 2.0.  Here, "ls dev/eclipse/sdks/ | wc -l" yields 22. From 5.0 orion, 4.4m5 Luna.... to 3.4.

Comment: Down voted because there is a much better answer below.  Install the JST server Adapters and you do not have to install all the stuff that comes with the EE version that you never use.

Comment: @AlainPannetier - I added a comment because the SO site suggested leaving one to explain why I did that.  It's not a personal insult, and I'm not asking you do delete it.  As for what kind of java developer you think I am, that's irrelevant.  Don't get your panties in a bunch.

Answer (score 137):

Depending on how you installed it, you might have skipped the "JST Server Adapters" (org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext) and "JST Server Adapters Extensions" feature that actually contains the Apache Tomcat support.

Comment: In Indigo, this seems to need also "JST Server Adapters Extensions"

Comment: @akavel, this was exactly my problem with Indigo!

Comment: @akavel, same with Juno classic :)

Comment: @akavel normal Eclipse Juno has this problem as well. This is odd because according to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/542192/ the extensions feature is supposed to only contain legacy adapters.

Comment: You get an accepted answer from me, I didn't want to have to reinstall my Eclipse for Java Developers :)

Answer (score 32):

I met the same problem before but my eclipse is indigo and also downloaded WTP... orz no tomcat found. However, I resolved by doing following:

1. Go to Help > Install New Software...
2. From the Work With, select "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo"
3. From the list, select "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
4. Then select "JST Server Adapters"

After installed this, when I add New Server, I can see Tomcat available for selection. :) hope this helps too~

Comment: For me, this required also installing "JST Server Adapters Extensions"

Comment: This works, I had to install that plugin seperately as described by sibley

Answer (score 19):

As akavel said, make sure "**JST Server Adapters Extensions**" are installed too.  Tomcat didn't show up for me until I installed that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used @sibley solution but tomcat8.5 and over were missing. To correct that I had to click on Help>Check for Update. This will bring all missing tomcat