# Apache Tomcat is missing in Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am planning to using Apache Tomcat for my development purpose in Eclipse IDE. I have created a webservice application, for this I need to configure Installed runtime as Tomcat Server, to run the service.

When I try to install it, I find it was missing in the list of servers.

[image: Tomcat Server Missing]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Comment: this is not duplicate... its actually issue with Eclipse 3.7. You don't have tomcat in list...

Comment: for anyone facing same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5155040/512100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window > Show View > Servers`. From there, `Right click > New > Server` and you should see a first group called `Apache`, with plenty of Tomcats to choose from.

It might depend on the version of Eclipse you are using. I know for sure that *Eclipse for Java EE Developers* contains these servers, *Eclipse Classic* or *Eclipse for Java Developers* might not include them.

Comment: its not included in Eclipse Version: 3.7.2 Build id: M20120208-0800, is there any chance to get that

Comment: Which flavour did you download? *Eclipse for Java EE Developers*, *Eclipse Classic*, *Eclipse for Java Developers*, other?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem and found this solution, may be it can help you: 
- 1st: Copy file servlet-api.jar in folder install tomcat:ex:C:\tomcat\common\lib\servlet-api.jar into folder install java ex: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.5\jre\lib\ext.
-2nd: open: C:\tomcat\conf\context.xml

add Text:

< Context reloadable = “true”>

WEB-INF/web.xml

…….

- 3rd: Download file tomcatPlugin….
- unzip into "plugin" folder of eclipse
- Start eclipse, go to Window\preference\
- In Preference Tab:

  - Chose Tomcat and config:

  +Tomcat version: Your installed tomcat version

  +Tomcat home: link to folder that you unzip tomcat (C:\Tomcat5.5)

  - Manager App username: admin

  Manager App password: admin

  Clik OK
- Restart Eclipse

OK. GOOD LUCK ^^

Source: http://maivanha.blogspot.com/2007/11/i.html