# Eclipse Kepler Server not Creating

Tags: java, eclipse

I was earlier using eclipse juno on linux enviroment. Now I have shifted to windows and installed eclipse kepler. I have already installed apache tomcat6 and its running successfully in browser.I am trying to run jsp files in eclipse by making server but tomcat is not showing.
I followed this way

- window
- preferences
- server
- runtime enviroment
- add

[image] but apache is not showing at all.Please see the screenshot

**EDIT**
I have even tried to download additional adapters but in the list tomcat is not there.Please see the below screenshot
[image]

Comment: I think this eclipse does not have adapter for `Tomcat Apache server`. Add the adapter for the same.

Comment: click download additional server adapters. select apache tomcat.

Comment: @Qadir When I am clicking on the `download additional adapters` then in the list tomcat is not there

Comment: @lakshman I did that way but its not found

Comment: read this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066088/eclipse-wtp-plugin-no-apache-tomcat-adapter

Comment: Try going to window => show view => other => Servers => servers then click ok. Then after go to the server tab next to your console tab, right click on the white space in you server tab and select new => Server , that should show a list of servers you can use, under apache, select it and add the tomcat server, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the apache option is not showing up then you need to download the server adapter for Apache. You can go to that by going to

Your JSP -->>right click and run on server --->Manually define a new server--->Download additional server adapter.

Comment: if its not showing up then you need to add facet in your web project.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add facet?

Comment: right click on your project then go to "properties" there you will find "project facets"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i started with kepler was not able to configure my JBOSS server.

Recheck is it `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` ?